# Installing SSL On apache2 & Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install ssl on my apache2.4.7 ubuntu 14.04 server 
I'm following the digital ocean tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority)
but it keeps redirecting me to the normal http version. This is my 000-default.conf in sites-available (even when I delete the whole content it still loads my website)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName xxxxxx.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/xxxxxx.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/xxxxxx.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile/etc/apache2/ssl/intermediate.crt    

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Whats the location of this content on your server ?

Comment: @ODelibalta /etc/apache2/sites-available

Comment: Keep your changes then run `apache2ctl configtest` to see if there is an error in your syntax. BTW, there is a high possibility that you are cached. Clear your local DNS, it would not hurt.

Comment: @ODelibalta btw the content is in 000-default.conf and that command says Syntax OK

Comment: @ODelibalta I get this in my error,log Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443

Comment: Might need to a2dismod default and a2enmod yournewsite. Then, service apache2 restart

Comment: Do a `kill 14937` from the cmd line and then restart apache.

Comment: @PanamaJack didn't do anything just created a new id

Comment: @HiradRoshandel Apache still won't start?

Comment: @PanamaJack apache starts. but the https is not working. That error i mentioned above only appears if I write Listen *:443 at the top of my .conf file.

Comment: You probably already have Listen *.443 in the main .conf file. or in the `ports.conf` file. You don't need to do it twice.

Comment: @PanamaJack yep I removed it. I can't figure out what the problem is. I dont even have <VirtualHost *:80> then why is loading my website

Comment: So then what is the problem after you remove it? What happens exactly when you browse via https?

Comment: @PanamaJack it loads  non https

Comment: There is probably a redirect set. What is the contents of your 80 vhost and your .htaccess file for your site if you're using one? Also do you have a control panel?

Comment: @PanamaJack I dont have any 80 vhost  in my 000-default.conf and in my sites availabe and enabled you can only see 000-default. also in var/www/html i have nothing its just 1 html file and there is no .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a process running on the 443 port so when apache tries to get on that, it fails.

`netstat -tlpn | grep 443`

use that to find out which process is using it. It should give you process id as well. 
`service <process> stop` 
or 
`kill <processID>` to kill the process that is using your 443 port. Clear your apache logs and restart apache.

Comment: I get this: tcp6        0      0 :::443(red)     :::*    LISTEN 14937/apache2

Comment: actually that error I mention aboved only appears when I put Listen *:443 at the top of my .conf file. when I remove it there is no error in my log